# why my nest grid-template-column not working? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have try to build two rows with two columns each, inside my right grid box however, it doesn't seem to be working. (it just appears as 4 rows) Can you all help me spot any mistake/ give me an advice of how to fix this pls?

```css
.about__container {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.about__link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: red;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__container container-fluid grid">
  <div class="about__content">
    <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, enim!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="about___link container grid">
    <div class="item link__youtube">
      <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, enim!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item link__article">
      <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, tempore!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item link__addfriend">
      <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, quia?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item link__achievement">
      <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, amet!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your css you used the wrong selector.
In your html the class is `.about___link` but you have used `.about__link` as css selector.
I changed it and it works but try to use a cleaner html and selectors wich are more readable :)

```css
.about__container {
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}

.about___link{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    background-color: red;
    grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__container container-fluid grid">
                <div class="about__content">
                  <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, enim!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="about___link container grid">
                    <div class="item link__youtube">
                        <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, enim!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item link__article">
                        <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum,
                            tempore!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item link__addfriend">
                        <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, quia?
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item link__achievement">
                        <p class="link-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, amet!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure (.container-fluid) is not overwriting the display property. Because, you wrote both classes in a single div tag.

Solution 1:
Keep the (about__container) in the (container-fluid) div as a child element.

Solution 2:
Inspect the element from your browser inspector and try to figure out the issue.

Solution 3: (not recommended)
Use !important after CSS property!

For example:

```
.about__container {
     display: grid !important;
     position: relative;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) !important;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100%;
     background-color:green;
     grid-gap: 30px;
 }
```